# Concatenate two lines on condition with awk

Tags: awk, concatenation, end-of-line

I'm trying to concatenate two lines when the number of fiels does not match a given number.

Here is an example of input file:

```
1, z
2
3
4
5, w
6
7
```

and here is the result I want:

```
1, z 2
3
4
5, w 6
7
```

I tried the following code:

```
awk '
{
   if (NF!=1){
   first=$0
   getline
   print first" ",$0}
   else {print $0}
}' $1
```

Here is what I obtain:

```
 2 z
3
4
 6 w
7
```

I don't understand why I get the next line first and then only the second field of the first line.

Comment: I add `^M` characters hidden somewhere. I should have known!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much more shorter version would be

```
$ awk 'ORS=NF == 1?"\n":FS' input
1, z 2
3
4
5, w 6
7
```

- `ORS` is output field separator
- `FS` field separator, which is space by default
- `NF == 1?"\n":FS'` if `NF`, number of fields equals to `1` then `ORS` is set to `\n` else is set to `FS`

Comment: Thanks. But it is strange, using your suggestion, I get exactly the same (wrong) output as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @bosonfute chances are that your input file may not be correctly formated as in the question. Please do check that

Comment: @bosonfute I have tested the script in `GNU Awk 3.1.5` it works fine there though :/

Comment: Thanks. Weird: I tried on a different VM. All the solutions provided here, including mine that I included in my question, give the correct output. On my own computer, everything gives the wrong output (the one in my question). I don't have a strange distribution: Linux Mint (Debian) and awk version is GNU Awk 4.0.X. On the VM, it is 3.1.7. Maybe awk version is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
awk 'NF!=1{printf "%s ", $0;next}1' file
```

Output :

```
1, z 2
3
4
5, w 6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NF>1?FS:RS)}' file
1, z 2
3
4
5, w 6
7
```

It prints newline if there is one field and else one blank (Field Separator)

Comment: Thanks. But it is strange, using your suggestion, I get exactly the same (wrong) output as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @bosonfute Then you indata is different from what you have posted here.  PS do not use  `getline`.  Google `why not use getline` and you see why.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about getline. I'll be careful now. Still I think my problem is due to awk version, as I mentioned in my reply to nu11p01n73R.